# Use javascript only in this form

Tags: javascript, html, forms

I have a form that will only display the next question once you have entered an input in the field. My trouble right now is, how will I display the next question using javascript only. What I am thinking about right now is to make a div in each of the question hide it then if the user have entered a value and clicked next the next question will not be hidden. My question is there another way to do that using **Javascript** only.

HTML codes below...there will be 20 `<div>`s in this form just posted 2 because the code is just the same only the labels are different

```
  <div id="q1">
        <label for="nanme">Full Name</label>
        <input class="input" id="name" name="name" type="text" placeholder="Full Name" value="" onkeyup="disable()">

        <div class="control-group">
          <div class="controls">
            <button id="nxtbtn" name="nxtbtn" disabled onclick="next()">Next</button>
          </div>
        </div>
  </div>

  <div id="q2" style="display:none;">
      <label for="Age">Age</label>
      <input class="input" id="age" name="age" type="text" placeholder="Age" value="">

        <div class="control-group">
          <div class="controls">
            <button id="btnbck" >Back</button>
          </div>
        </div>      
        <div class="control-group">
          <div class="controls">
            <button id="button" >Next</button>
          </div>
        </div>      
  </div>
```

JS

```
function disable(){
  document.getElementById('nxtbtn').removeAttribute("disabled");
}
function next(){
    document.getElementById('q2').style.display = 'block';
    document.getElementById('q1').style.display = 'none';
}
```

This [site](http://yescarloans.net/) will help you to see what I would like to do with my form

Comment: Put them in a class. Change the class of each consecutive when an input of previous one is given.

Comment: As in two classes. Use css to hide and display them.

Answer (score 0):

You can add a count variable to know next question's number, then show it and hide the previous question:
Example:

```
var count = 2;
function disable(){
  document.getElementById('nxtbtn').removeAttribute("disabled");
}
function next(){
    document.getElementById('q'+ count).style.display = 'block';
    document.getElementById('q' + (count -1)).style.display = 'none';
    count ++;
}
```

This is a good way for several questions.

You can change style by CSS classes

```
.hide{
  display: none;
}

.show{
  display: block;
}
```

And apply this class in your tags depending on the case:

Final **Javascript:**

```
var count = 2;
    function disable(){
      document.getElementById('nxtbtn').removeAttribute("disabled");
    }
    function next(){
        document.getElementById('q'+ count).className = "show";
        document.getElementById('q' + (count -1)).className = "hide";
        count ++;
    }
```

Final **HTML**:

```
<div id="q1" class="show">
        <label for="nanme">Full Name</label>
        <input class="input" id="name" name="name" type="text" placeholder="Full Name" value="" onkeyup="disable()">

        <div class="control-group">
          <div class="controls">
            <button id="nxtbtn" name="nxtbtn" disabled onclick="next()">Next</button>
          </div>
        </div>
  </div>

  <div id="q2" class="hide">
      <label for="Age">Age</label>
      <input class="input" id="age" name="age" type="text" placeholder="Age" value="">

        <div class="control-group">
          <div class="controls">
            <button id="btnbck" >Back</button>
          </div>
        </div>      
        <div class="control-group">
          <div class="controls">
            <button id="button" >Next</button>
          </div>
        </div>      
  </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Hide all questions except for the first one:

```
// CSS
.question + .question {
  display: none;
}
```

When users click next, hide the first question, show the next question:

```
// JS
var step = 1;
$('button').click(function() {
  $('#q' + step++).hide();
  $('#q' + step).show();
});
```

[codepen](http://codepen.io/alex-wilmer/pen/Joazpq)